# How do I call writehex on a new line?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

I have a program that takes a string as input and outputs the decimal number representing amount of characters in the string, the hexvalue and the string itself.

The issue I am having is that if use `call writedec`,  I want to be able to use `call writehex` after it, but print it on a new line. Currently, it prints on the same line.

However, if use mov al, `0ah`, `call writehex` will print `0ah`, instead of the hex value of the decimal

```
call writedec
call writehex
```

results in `130000000d`
but I need:

```
13
0000000d

call writedec
mov al, 0Ah
call writehex
```

always results with

```
13
0000000Ah
```

Comment: You want to use `WriteChar` for obvious reasons. You might need `CR LF` though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did, but I must have been missing something. Works fine with `mov al, 0Ah` followed by `call writechar`